# What am i missing for this to work? (Zener Diode)

Tags: zener, lm317

[image: Zener circuit]

Since the zener breakdown voltage is set to 5v, i actually thought that the voltage would be 0, since it goes directly to ground, I just wanted to try a "simple overvoltage protection". How is it that the voltage is 5v instead of 0? Without the diode, the voltage is around 22 volt or so.

Can anyone explain why this is and maybe give a few examples on how to fix it? 
(This is my first time working with Zener Diodes)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the Zener action with a 'crowbar' circuit. A Zener will limit the voltage whereas a crowbar circuit will short out the supply in the event of an over-voltage. The crowbar short can usually only be removed by cycling the power.

The Zener diode will start to conduct in the reverse direction when the voltage across it reaches about 5 V. From then on very small increases in voltage will cause it to pass an exponentially greater current. At the same time the voltage will increase slightly above 5 V.

The problem with your arrangement is that if the regulator can pass, say 1 A, before going into limiting then your Zener has to handle all that power. \$P = V \cdot I = 5 \cdot 1 = 5~W\$. It will get hot.

**Crowbar circuit**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flTtXq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Crowbar circuit.*

This is a basic crowbar circuit. When the supply voltage rises above 4.7 V the Zener starts to conduct. When the voltage across R1 gets high enough SCR1 will be triggered and pretty-well short out the supply. The thyristor has to pass all the current (1 A in our example above) but this time the voltage across the device is only about 0.5 V so \$P = V \cdot I = 0.5 \cdot 1 = 0.5~W\$. Cool!

The thyristor will stay on until the current though it is reduced to zero by interrupting the supply.

History lesson: the term crowbar protection comes from the railway third-rail electrification. If the lineman saw a problem and needed an emergency isolation of the track power supply he would throw his crowbar to short the third rail to one of the running rails and trip out the breaker.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i was looking for :D

Comment: You're welcome. Look up crowbar circuits to get proper component values. There may be a capacitor on the gate too to prevent small noise triggering the crowbar. Please accept this answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 2):

You said yourself, the zener breakdown voltage is 5 V.  That means it's going to clamp the reverse voltage across it to 5 V.  I can't imagine why you would think it should clamp it to 0.  If you want a voltage clamped to 0, put a wire across it.

The schematic is too small to easily read, but it appears you put the zener on the output of a linear regulator.  If the regulator is trying to put out less than 5 V, then the zener won't conduct, and it might as well not have been there.

If the regulator is trying to put out more than 5 V, then the zener and regulator will be fighting each other.  If the zener can handle whatever current the regulator can provide, then the voltage will be limited to 5 V, but both the zener and regulator will get hot.  Unfortunately, the maximum current is not defined, so you will have difficulty predicting exactly what will happen.

It's not clear what your purpose is in adding the zener to the output.  There are better ways to guarantee the output voltage won't exceed some value.

Comment: Sorry about the small image, if you right click on the image and then click on"copy the image address) you will see it in a higher resolution. 

"It's not clear what your purpose is in adding the zener to the output" like i said, i was just trying to make a somewhat simple overvoltage protection and i thought that it would work. But all the comments here suggests that i have got the Zener diode completely wrong and have to read some more about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Others answered your question, let me just add that you can do this with trisils, also known as thyristor surge protection devices. It behaves like the crowbar device explained by @transistor, but in single package.

It is essentially voltage controlled triac without gate. It will give you voltage close to zero when it opens, which if I understand is what you wanted from your design.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yes that i exactly what i want. I will check that out! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Zener diode is doing exactly what it is supposed to do - it prevents the voltage across itself from rising above its rated voltage.

If you apply a slowly increasing voltage across a Zener diode, the diode will only pass an extremely small current, until you apprach the rated voltage, when the current will start to increase.  Above the rated voltage, the Zener current will increase rapidly of very small increases in voltage, as the Zener attempts to hold the voltage to its rated voltage.  If the power source can only supply a small current, the Zener will maintain its rated voltage.  With a more powerful voltage source, the Zener (or the voltage source) may be destroyed as the zener draws excessive current.

Comment: I see, Thank you for the detailed explanation! I found a zener protection circuit on the web for LM317, Do you think that this will work to turn off the output once the zener voltage is reached?

Link: http://electronics-diy.com/schematics/1188/lm317-overvoltage-protection.gif

Comment: @Xane - That is a rather dangerous protection circuit. It causes the - output to float with respect to ground. It will work to prevent the load from drawing current,  but the + output will remain at 5 volts.

Comment: I see, what is your opinion about the "Crowbar Circuit" that transistor commented about:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/lTtXq.png
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Zener diode has following characteristics

1. It will act as open circuit when voltage across its is less than clamping voltage Vz (5V in your case)
2. If voltage across its is greater than Vz, it will clamp voltage to Vz (5V in your case)

[image: V-I Characteristics]

Red encircled point is point where you are operating your zener diode. Since voltage across diode > Vz, Output = 5v ( zener diode clamping voltage )

Comment: I didn't know that, like i said before i obsiously got zener diodes all wrong but this definetly helped! thanks a lot :)